# Не могу запустить локальный сервер venv Python

Tags: python, django, venv

Вот код:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from django.conf.urls import include
from django.urls import path
from django.conf.urls import include
from django.conf.urls import url

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path(r'', include('journal.urls')),
]
```

Вот ошибка:

```
File "C:\python\lib\threading.py", line 980, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\python\lib\threading.py", line 917, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Sveta\PycharmProjects\Журнал трейдов\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Sveta\PycharmProjects\Журнал трейдов\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 134, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "C:\Users\Sveta\PycharmProjects\Журнал трейдов\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 475, in check
    all_issues = checks.run_checks(
  File "C:\Users\Sveta\PycharmProjects\Журнал трейдов\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 88, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs, databases=databases)
  File "C:\Users\Sveta\PycharmProjects\Журнал трейдов\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 14, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "C:\Users\Sveta\PycharmProjects\Журнал трейдов\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 24, in check_resolver
    return check_method()
  File "C:\Users\Sveta\PycharmProjects\Журнал трейдов\venv\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 494, in check
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "C:\Users\Sveta\PycharmProjects\Журнал трейдов\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 57, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\Sveta\PycharmProjects\Журнал трейдов\venv\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 715, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "C:\Users\Sveta\PycharmProjects\Журнал трейдов\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 57, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\Sveta\PycharmProjects\Журнал трейдов\venv\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 708, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "C:\python\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 850, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\Sveta\PycharmProjects\Журнал трейдов\venv\Scripts\journal_trade\journal_trade\urls.py", line 24, in <module>
    path(r'', include('journal.urls')),
  File "C:\Users\Sveta\PycharmProjects\Журнал трейдов\venv\lib\site-packages\django\urls\conf.py", line 38, in include
    urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
  File "C:\python\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 984, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'journal.urls'
```

Подскажите, что я не так делаю?

Comment: Логичный вопрос - что такое journal?

Comment: Это название приложения venv

Comment: Где оно находится, как создано и что содержит? В общем, какие действия вы предприняли, чтобы этот `include('journal.urls')` заставить работать?

Comment: Создано с помощью команды ```python manage.py startapp journal```. Находится приложение по следующему пути ```C:\Users\Sveta\PycharmProjects\Журнал трейдов\venv\Scripts\journal_trade\journal```. ```journal_trade``` это название проекта, который создавался командой ```django-admin startproject journal_trade```.

Comment: а запустить локальный сервер, я пытаюсь командой ```python manage.py runserver```. После чего мне и выдает эту ошибку

Comment: Как минимум, виртуальное окружение должно быть внутри проекта, а не проект внутри папки виртуального окружения.

Comment: Ну вот смотрите, виртуальное окружение я перенес по следующему адресу ```C:\Users\Sveta\PycharmProjects\Журнал трейдов\venv```, а сам проект с файлом ```manage.py``` находится тут ```C:\Users\Sveta\PycharmProjects\Журнал трейдов\journal_trade```, но выдает туже самую ошибку